# External monitors and backlight control of internal monitor don't work with ThinkPad E14 Gen 3 (AMD Ryzen 5500U)

Tags: monitors, thinkpad, brightness

I have installed a Debian Sid with kernel version 5.10.0-7-amd64 on my new ThinkPad device. When I connect external monitors via the Lenovo USB-C dock or even the internal HDMI socket, they are not detected by GNOME or `xrandr`. Additionally, changing the brightness of the internal display doesn't work (tested with keyboard shortcuts, GNOME settings, and manually setting `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`).

When I start a live system via a USB stick, everything works fine.

Here you can find some basic system information:

ThinkPad E14 Gen 3 (AMD Ryzen 5500U)

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 174a
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series (rev 03)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne (rev c2)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

I am very unsure how to debug such a problem and how to collect proper information for this purpose. If you could help me with this, I would be very glad.

Comment: What I did once was to create a list of the installed p;rograms on a working system usting "apt list --installed" and awk to pick out the package names, then used the list as an install list for the other identical misbehaving machine. In my case, it worked because initally I only installed a subset of the possible packages on both machines. There are probably more eloquent ways.